# Why does Stack Overflow have an old copy of my resume saved for Stack Overflow Jobs?

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

If I go to the jobs site and click on a job that says "Easy Apply" I see this `.docx` resume:

[image: Saved resume that should not be saved picture example]

When I download it I see a very outdated copy of my resume. Cool, easy enough, there is a "remove" button for me, so I click the "remove" link and upload my new resume (which is a `.pdf`)

[image: Resume saving when it should not picture example]

I *do not* select the "Save resume for future applications" option. I click to apply for the job and then if I come back to this same page I see that my old outdated `.docx` resume is still saved there like this:

[image: Saved resume that should not be saved picture example]

I cannot find any place on my profile or developer story where this old resume resides.

Why is Stack Overflow saving any copy of my resume when I have not pressed the "Save resume for future applications" checkbox and where is this old copy coming from?

Comment: Possibly from [Job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current), under "Saved resume"

Comment: @AndrewT. it looks like that was it. Still a confusing UI (perhaps they should add wording to explain where this one is coming from)

Answer (score 22):

I don't think that this is [generally] confusing. Naturally, no interface will be clear to *everyone*, but I think on balance this is working as it should.

You previously uploaded a CV, and asked to save it for future applications. That's the one you're seeing "by default".

Then you uploaded a new CV, and *didn't* ask to save it for future applications: it was just a one-off for that particular application.

It is therefore not surprising that your previously saved CV is still there for your next application. It's still saved, because you didn't do anything to un-save it.

It is also not surprising that it can be found under "Saved resume" in [your Jobs preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).

Comment: So the "remove" link didn't work, and shouldn't work?

Comment: @anatolyg Of course it worked, it was removed from that particular application, not from the account

Comment: @anatolyg It worked fine!

Comment: I disagree. Most people (maybe 60%) will correctly assume that they are removing that resume from the current submission. But some will expect it to be removed from the system at large, especially since other elements in the same area (namely the checkbox) do affect the system at large.

Comment: Seems like it could pretty easily be remedied by changing "remove" to "remove from application"

Comment: For me the thing that is confusing is that you have this "Remove" button and then right below it you have a checkbox to "Save resume for future applications". One of these options is for removing the resume from your **current** session and the other option is to save it globally. That is a confusing UI. If I'm able to save something globally then I should have an option to remove something globally

Comment: @speciesUnknown citation needed on that 40% statistic. To my knowledge, nobody has ever complained about this before.

Comment: @maxshuty It's pretty standard. When you add payment methods to some checkout process, there is often a "remember this for next time", but you wouldn't expect "remove payment method" on _that checkout process_ to affect some global cache elsewhere. That's why the wording specifically calls out the permanent nature of _just that one option_.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Its my estimate, I said "maybe". This comes from experience of people's behaviour when I put this sort of thing in front of them.